# JSON schema, validate that only one object in array has property equals to value

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jsonschema

I have a payload that i want to validate using JSON schema, but there this case that i don't know how to translate to a schema.

Let's say i have this object:

```
{
  jobs: [
    { title: "Developer", salary: "100", actual: false },
    { title: "Plumber", salary: "200", actual: true },
    { title: "Teacher", salary: "100", actual: false }
  ]
}
```

i want to write a schema that validates that IF there are objects in the `jobs` array, one (and only one) of them MUST have the `actual` key set to `true`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you share your JSON Schema so far? It is possible, and I will provide you a solution =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You want to set up a schema with the "items", "contains", "minContains" and "maxContains" keywords that leverage the "if"/"then" ability to write conditionals. That is, in pseudocode:

- I have an object with **property** "jobs", whose value must be an array.
- the **items** in that array are objects, which have **properties** named "title", "salary" and "actual" (with specific types for each of those values).
- either the "jobs" array has zero **items**, or it must **contain** exactly one item which has a **property** named "actual" whose value is a **constant** of value true.